# TextField input always starts uppercase

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

In my Flutter app, even though I add `textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none` to the TextField and its `keyboardType` is `TextInputType.emailAddress`, the text field always starts with an uppercase character when I start typing. I have to manually turn off uppercase from my keyboard. And quite frankly I don't want it to happen like that. How can I solve this problem?

My Widget:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: TextField(
        onChanged: function(),
        obscureText: this.hintText == "Password" ? true : false,
        keyboardType: this.keyboardType,
        textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: this.hintText,
          contentPadding:
              EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
          ),
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: _colorPalette.darkBlue, width: 1.0),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(this.size)),
          ),
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: _colorPalette.darkBlue, width: 2.0),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(this.size)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: As it looks like the keyboard I'm using which is Fleksy causes this issue. There was no capitalization issue when I changed the keyboard to GBoard. So there seems to be a problem with Fleksy rather than the Flutter's configurations.

Comment: No problem :) have a nice one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code always gives lower case for me:

```
TextField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none,
),
```

Even if I leave out any or both of the two statements inside the TextField!

I guess you're testing on a real device. Maybe it's your keyboad: I'm using Gboard.

Comment: I actually am using a real device to debug and my keyboard is Fleksy. It also happens when I try to log into Instagram account. So there's a high possibility that keyboard is the problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So how about making sure by trying Gboard?

Comment: Yep, Gboard doesn't have the problem.